# managed object subclasses are not generating implementation files and are incorrectly named

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

In Xcode 4.6, I generated plenty of managed object subclass files without any problem. But now that I'm trying to do it in Xcode 5, it generates only a .h file. The header file lists the correct @properties, but it takes on the name of my project, rather than the name of the core data entity I selected. Just to be sure I hadn't forgotten something, I carefully followed  [these steps](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_mo_class.html) . What could be going on? Thanks

Comment: I think I had this problem once.  Try shutting down and restarting, I think that fixed it for me. I can't recall the exact details of what I did but it seemed to be related to the switch from 4.6 to 5.  Also check you are using 5.0.1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Updating and rebooting did not fix the entity in question. I tried reconstructing it a few times, generating a subclass immediately from the blank entity and repeatedly as I added attributes. It didn't work a few time, but I finally got the complete entity to generate correctly. It is identical to the one that still doesn't work (except in name). No idea.

Comment: I've never heard of anything like this. It's not normal, so it's not like there's some option you should (or should not) be using to make it work normally. I think we need more information, because based on your description all anyone can really say is "that shouldn't happen".